# How can we measure the "fit" between the softmax outputs and Dirichlet distribution?

Tags: dirichlet-distribution, softmax

For simplicity, I'll consider classification with 3 classes.

Then, softmax outputs can be considered as the set of points in 2-simplex.
I want to measure the 'fit' of this softmax output with target Dirichlet distribution.

Can anyone give some suggestion?